# Ubuntu 20.04 no longer contains font Noto Sans Syriac Eastern

Tags: fonts, packaging, debian

In Ubuntu 18.04, the package `fonts-noto-unhinted` contained the font Noto Sans Syriac Eastern, i.e. `/usr/share/fonts/truetype/noto/NotoSansSyriacEastern-Regular.ttf`. However, in Ubuntu 20.04, no package contains that font. There is only `/usr/share/fonts/truetype/noto/NotoSansSyriac-Regular.ttf` in `fonts-noto-core` and Black and Thin variants in `fonts-noto-extra`.

I checked, and Debian Unstable still has the Eastern and Western variants, and they are also listed on the Google Noto page.

So I was wondering why Ubuntu no longer ships these variants. I cannot see that there was a unification of the variants upstream. The issue is that our production system runs on both Ubuntu versions, so either font will fail for one system.

Does anybody know what happend to the Noto Sans Syriac families in 20.04?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson good catch. I had indeed misunderstood the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu 20.04 has the very same selection as Debian unstable (not sure what you see that I don't), and I think Debian gets the fonts from [here](https://github.com/googlefonts/noto-fonts). There is an [upstream issue](https://github.com/googlefonts/noto-fonts/issues/1863) about it. Looks like they admit they made a mistake and will split it into separate fonts again.

In the meantime you can try to download *Noto Sans Syriac Eastern* from [here](https://www.google.com/get/noto/#sans-syrc-eastern) and install it manually.

Comment: Thanks! I searched debian for the file and found it here: https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=contents&keywords=NotoSansSyriacEastern-Regular.ttf&mode=path&suite=unstable&arch=any

Thanks also for the link to the bug report. I did install the font manually for now.

Comment: @Frederik: That's odd, considering that it's not [here](https://packages.debian.org/sid/all/fonts-noto-core/filelist). Anyway, good that the answer was helpful.